# .NET Core web application to linux server get user

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, authentication

I deployed an C# .NET Core 2.0 application on Linux ubuntu 16.04 with a MySQL database on AWS.
The server and db are communicating and the applications runs.
However, I can't seem to get the user who is using the application in code-behind/controller.

I tried enviroment_variables and identity however it always returns null or the user on the Linux machine.

So in short, how can I get the user who is accessing my C# .NET Core application that is deployed on Linux?

Comment: If you can't post the code for legal reasons, consider creating a new temporary project with only the necessary code to reproduce your problem and share it with us.

Comment: Issues like this are usually caused by two issues 1) HTTP version 1.0 vs 1.1 2) Content Type which specifies the webbrowser.  The wrong webbrowser is in the request.  The solution is usually to add header to the request or add option in the server to accept the headers.  When a client connects to a server the headers in the webpage and the headers in the request are used to negotiate the options used to communicate.  So the solution is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to capture the headers.  Then compare working and non working request/response.